# I believe that the Close Votes quality check test occurs two clicks too early

Tags: bug, review, vote-to-close

> I am reporting what I would call a bug in the Close Votes quality check test

By 'Close Votes', I mean *the Close Votes page of the Review pages* at https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/0000000. By 'quality check test', I mean *the Close Votes that have no effect on any question and are simply there to check if a user would select the correct option or not*.

I was just reviewing some Close Votes earlier today (which if you ask me, more people need to do) and I came across a question that seemed fine. I was curious as to what reason(s) had been given for the previous Close Vote(s), so I clicked on the Close button to see which option(s) had been selected on the 'Why should this question be closed' popup window.

Instead of seeing which reasons the previous voter(s) had given as usual on the popup window, I got a message telling me that it was a test and I had chosen incorrectly. Now I can take an incorrect decision on my record, because there won't be many others. However, it just seems to me that this message appears too early.

My argument is simple. When we *actually* vote to close a question, we click on the 'Vote to Close' button in the 'Why should this question be closed' popup window, *not* on the 'Close' button in the Close Votes page. Furthermore, we can't even click on the 'Vote to Close' button until we have first selected a reason for the Close Vote. So it *seems* as though reviewers are being judged two clicks too early.

> **Can the Close Votes quality test occur when we click on the 'Vote to Close' button in the 'Why should this question be closed' popup window and *not* on the 'Close' button in the Close Votes page?**

Comment: Shoot... if only I'd searched using the word 'audit' instead of 'test', I could have saved some time here. Thanks though.

Comment: It happens. In any case, I totally agree that the problem at hand should be fixed.

Comment: I don't agree with the accepted answer to that question, that it would be difficult to implement though.